# Initbinder for List of Strings

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, spring-mvc

Hallo everyone i'm trying to use the initbinder annotations in order to match the values i receive from a multiply list box.The values from the list box are String values.Iinitially i did it with the following way just to match only one choice(i didn't add the multiply choice yet) and it works perfectly fine. The code is the following:

At the controller i have this:

```
 @InitBinder 
public void initBinderResearch(WebDataBinder b) {

    b.registerCustomEditor(Research.class, new ResearchEditor());

}
```

At the debuging i can see that the binding of the research_area values is not successful.But i don't take any exception or error.Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong and this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override `PropertyEditor.setAsText(List<String> text)` because it not exists in parent class and `WebDataBinder` will not use this method to make string to object conversions.

If you register your original `ResearchEditor` and change the property from type `Research` to type `List<Research>` in your backing form model, the WebDataBinder will convert thems.

Comment: So that you say is to replace it with this:  b.registerCustomEditor(List<Research>, new ResearchEditor());  ?

Comment: No, I say that you only need to change the *type* of your backing form model. The web data binder will do the String->List<String>->List<Research> conversion.

Comment: I'm sorry that i sending again but i can't understand how can i do this.Can you saw me on the code i provide please?

Comment: Post your controller handler method so I can see your Research variable.

Comment: With the way that you explain me now i create for each one of the input values a list.What about if i want all this values in the same list.I want to create the following xml format:     <research_areas>
<research_area>one<research_area><research_area>another<research_area><research_areas>.But now i create this one:<research_areas><research_area> one </research_area></research_areas><research_areas><research_area>another</research_area></research_areas>